# How to compute $2^{2475} \bmod 9901$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to compute $2^{2475} \bmod 9901$?

My work:
$$2^{2475} = 2^{5^2\cdot 9\cdot 11} = 1048576^{5\cdot 9\cdot 11} = (-930)^{5\cdot 9\cdot 11} \bmod 9901$$

but I got stuck after this. Any further computation continuing from where I got stuck results in numbers that are too large for me to work with.

Comment: As $9901$ is prime and $\equiv1\pmod4,$ $$\left(\dfrac2p\right)=(-1)^{(p-1)/4}$$

Comment: By Euler's theorem: $\gcd(2,9901)=1\implies2^{\phi(9901)}\equiv1\pmod{9901}$.

Since $9901$ is prime, $\phi(9901)=9900$, hence $2^{9900}\equiv1\pmod{9901}$.

Hence $2^{9900}\equiv(2^{2475})^{4}\equiv1\pmod{9901}$.

Now we need to solve the equation $x^{4}\equiv1\pmod{9901}$.

Comment: So the answer is x=1?

Comment: @barakmanos, By my hint above, we have found $$x^{(9901-1)/4}\equiv1\pmod{9901}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$9901$ is prime and $9900=4\cdot2475$ then $$(2^{2475})^4=2^{9900}\equiv 1\pmod{9901}$$ Hence we can solve in the field $\Bbb F_{9901}$ the equation $$X^4=1$$ Wolfram gives $X=1000,X=8901,X=9900$ and we have to pick $\color{red}{X=1000}$ because it corresponds to $2^{2475}$.

Comment: 1. $X=1$ is also a solution to $X^4\equiv1\pmod{9901}$. 2. Why does $1000$ "corresponds to $2^{2475}$"??? 3. I'm pretty sure that there's a mathematical way (other than WolframAlpha) for solving $X^4\equiv1\pmod{9901}$. 4. I think that it's worth explaining the statement "$(2^{2475})^4=2^{9900}\equiv 1\pmod{9901}$" (see my comment to the question).

Comment: $1$ and $-1=9900$ are trivial solutions and note that, similarly, $1000=-8901$, however here an explanation: $2475=3^3\cdot 5^2\cdot 11$. You have in the field $\Bbb F_{9901}$ the following partial calculations $2^{11}= 2048$, $2048^3=5210$; $5210^3=5718$; $5718^5=7047$ and finally $7047^5-1000=0$. Thanks for your comment. Best regards.

Comment: Note ,please, that I have taken power $3$ just twice (with $2048$ and $5210$). This shows that in $2475=3^3\cdot 5^2\cdot 11$ I made a lapse with exponent $3$. The true exponent of $3$ is $2$ of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *fast exponentiation algorithm* (see description in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898234/fast-exponentiation-algorithm-how-to-arrive-at-it/1898259#1898259). It requires $11$ squarings and $6$ multiplications.
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
\hline
n&S\bmod9901&&P\bmod9901\\
\hline
2475&2&\to&2\\
1237&4&\to&8\\
618&16&&8\\
309&256&\to&2048\\
154& 6130&&2048\\
77&2605&\to& 8302\\
38& 3840&& 8302\\
19&3011&\to&7198\\
9&6706&\to&2413\\
4& 94&&2413\\
2&8836&&2413\\
1&5511&\to&\color{red}{1000}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you made a mistake early.  Remember your rules of exponents.

$$2^{5^2\times9\times11}=(2^5)^{5\times9\times11}=32^{5\times9\times11}$$

Lab bhattacharjee's method is probably the best for this specific case.  Failing that, it shouldn't be too hard to calculate by a method like [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) with a computer program or even just a calculator.  If we're squaring numbers at most, the products won't exceed $9900^2<10^8$. I believe this can be done in as few as $15$ multiplications.