# Provide an efficient algorithm for computing $(a + b \sqrt{3})^n$?

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, exponentiation, integers

Provide an efficient algorithm that takes three integers as input and returns two integers that satisfy the condition. Only simple arithmetic operations are allowed (square root operation is not permitted).

Input: $(a, b, n)$ where $a, b, n$ are positive integers greater than $0$.

Output: $(c, d)$ where $c$ and $d$ are integers that satisfy the following condition:
$$ (a + b \sqrt{3})^n = c + d \sqrt{3}$$

Thought it was an interesting problem, haven't come up with a solution yet.

Initially wanted to post the question in StackOverflow but I thought it was more math heavy.

Comment: Do you count exponentiation as a simple operation?

Comment: Have you considered tracing out solutions for small values of $n$? That may be one strategy.

Comment: Hint:  The binomial theorem states that $(x+y)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$.  Use $x=a$ and $y=b\sqrt{3}$.  Recognize then that every other term will have $\sqrt{3}$ raised to an even power and thus can be written as an integer, and the remaining terms will be an integer multiple of $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel i believe not, only the primitive operations (+,-,*,/)

Comment: @JBKing I've tried that but the left side of the equation becomes messy very quickly.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, that's a really helpful theorem! but how would we take care of root for odd squares using primitive operations?

Comment: Recursively compute the powers would be my initial thought.

Comment: Only way I see is binomial expanding. The tentative induction is not possible because you need for this a general expression which is precisely what you want to find.

Comment: @Piquito OP does not ask for general expression but for algorithm, and that can be done more efficiently than using binomial expansion or simple recursion, see my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is similar to having multiplication in complex numbers
$$(x+yi)(u+vi)=(xu-yv)+(xv+yu)i$$ Just instead of imaginary $i$ you have $\sqrt{3}$. So 
$$(x+y\sqrt{3})(u+v\sqrt{3})=(xu+3yv)+(xv+yu)\sqrt{3}$$
Now basically abstracting this idea to pairs of integers, you have 
$$(x,y)\cdot(u,v)=(xu+3yv,xv+yu)$$
Using this "$\cdot$" $n$ times correctly (actually $n-1$ times), you can calculate $n$-th power of a number. Notice that there are only basic arithmetic operations involved.

### Efficience

Since you wanted also efficient algorithm, you can speed this up by using fast exponentiation. Basic idea is that instead of calculating $x$,$x^2$,$x^3$,etc, you just calculate 
\begin{align}
x^2 &= x \cdot x \\
x^4 &= x^2 \cdot x^2  \\
x^8 &= x^4 \cdot x^4  \\
&\vdots \\
\end{align}
and then combine the results correctly. This results on average in $\log_2{n}$  multiplication steps as compared to $n$ steps when using naive approach. There are other tricks to speed exponentiation up, suggest you to check them  [Fast exponentiation algorithm - How to arrive at it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898234/fast-exponentiation-algorithm-how-to-arrive-at-it), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring.

### Algorithm Pseudocode

To be even more specific, lets construct one such algorithm. Let's pick for example this fast exponentiation algorithm:

```
Function exp-by-squaring(x, n)
    if n = 0  then return  1;
    else if n is even  then return exp-by-squaring(x * x,  n / 2);
    else if n is odd  then return x * exp-by-squaring(x * x, (n - 1) / 2);
```

Now replacing $x$ with pair of numbers $a,b$, and similarly the multiplication with the one described above, we get:

```
Function exp-by-squaring(a, b, n)
    if n = 0  then return  (1,0);
    else if n is even  then return exp-by-squaring(a*a+3b*b, 2ab,  n / 2);
    else if n is odd  then 
        (c,d) = exp-by-squaring(a*a+3b*b, 2ab, (n - 1) / 2);
        return (ac+3bd,ad+bc);
```

This by the way shows how you can calculate powers in general, you just need to have multiplication defined. Even in cases where it first looks like the problem is only solvable by recursions, this trick allows to skip many steps.

### Python example

Now if you turn this into python (or any programming language you like), you can play with it:

```
def exp(a, b, n):
  if n == 0: 
    return (1,0)
  elif n % 2 == 0:
    return exp(a*a+3*b*b, 2*a*b,  n / 2)    
  elif n % 2 == 1:
    (c,d) = exp(a*a+3*b*b, 2*a*b, (n - 1) / 2)
    return (a*c+3*b*d,a*d+b*c)
```

For example

```
print exp(1,1,20)
```

yields

```
(268377088, 154947584)
```

And indeed, $(1+\sqrt{3})^{20} = 268377088+154947584\sqrt{3}$

Also notice there were only $5$ multiplications done, compared to naive $19$:

\begin{align}
(1+\sqrt{3})^2 &= (1+\sqrt{3}) \cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\\
(1+\sqrt{3})^4 &= (1+\sqrt{3})^2 \cdot (1+\sqrt{3})^2\\
(1+\sqrt{3})^8 &= (1+\sqrt{3})^4 \cdot (1+\sqrt{3})^4\\
(1+\sqrt{3})^{16} &= (1+\sqrt{3})^8 \cdot (1+\sqrt{3})^8\\
(1+\sqrt{3})^{20} &= (1+\sqrt{3})^4 \cdot (1+\sqrt{3})^{16}\\
\end{align}

Comment: "This usually results in less multiplication steps than calculating all intermediate powers" - this phrase sounds like it can unluckily happen that fast exponentiation will use *more* multiplications than the simplest algorithm, which is not true. I'd say that it does $\log_2 n$ multiplications, compared to usual $n$.

Comment: @lisyarus Good point, I have rephrased that to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Sil very nice man, marking as solution

Comment: you don't need special case for 1

Comment: @RiaD Nice catch, you are right. Technically it might save some time but that is negligible anyway, so removed it for simplicity. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Hint: let $(a+b\sqrt{3})^n = c_n+d_n \sqrt{3}$. Then $(a+b\sqrt{3})^{n+1} = (a c_n + 3 b d_n) +(a d_n + b c_n)\sqrt{3}$ which gives the double recurrence $c_{n+1}=a c_n + 3 b d_n, d_{n+1}=a d_n + b c_n$ with $c_1=a, d_1=b$, that can easily be turned into a workable algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

Consider this as a recursion:

$(a_n+b_n\sqrt{3})=(a+b\sqrt{3})^n = (a+b\sqrt{3})(a+b\sqrt{3})^{n-1} = (a+b\sqrt{3})(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}\sqrt{3}) = aa_{n-1}+3bb_{n-1}+(ab_{n-1}+a_{n-1}b)\sqrt{3}$

Note that you can consider these as elements of a $\mathbb Q$-vector space with the base vectors $1$ and $\sqrt{3}$. With regard to this basis we can write thre recursion as:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a_n \\ b_n \end{pmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}a & 3b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}}_{=:M}\begin{pmatrix}a_{n-1}\\ b_{n-1}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a & 3b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}^n \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Now the $n$-th power of $M$ can efficiently be computed if you first  diagonalize $M$ to $M=TDT^{-1}$ Then $M^n = TDT^-1TDT^-1 \cdots TDT^{-1} = TD^nT^{-1}$. Then $D^n$ is just the $n$-th power of the diagonal matrix $D$ which is easy to compute as you just have to take the entries of $D$ to the power of $n$.

Comment: Diagonalization can force matrix entries to be non-integer, thus considerably complicating the task.

Comment: You're right, however you don't need to use integers, you can use floating point arithmetic for doing so and then round the result if you keep track of the precision/size of the integers.

Comment: Using floating point numbers for a task that has an efficient solution involving only integers is always a very bad idea.

Comment: Why do you think so? As I said you just need to make sure that you choose a floating point type that allows for enough accuracy.

Comment: This is the correct way to go.  Just use normal matrix integer exponentiation instead of diagonization$M^n = M^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor \cdot 2 + n\%2} = \left(M^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\right)^2 \times M^{n\%2}$

Comment: @flawr What does "eniugh accuracy" mean? You still are going to have numerical errors, which are hard to overcome. Furthermore, integers are several times faster.  If the input can be arbitrary large, one can use variable-sized integers, which are a lot easier and faster then arbitrary-precision floating-points.

Comment: @DanielV This is the same as Sil's answer, but due to the nature of this matrices, matrix multiplication will be 2 times slower and will compute the same values twice.