# Evaluate $a^n$ using the binary expansion of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Use the following algorithm to devise an algorithm for computing $a^n$,

[image]

**Hint**: use binary expansion of $n$ to evaluate $a^n$.

The following algorithm is based on the above algorithm to evaluate $a^n$, but I don't see that it does anything extra and I don't see it using the hint too,

[image]

**Question**: We can use both algorithms above to evaluate $a^n$. I don't see how algorithm presented above based on the first algorithm above does answer the question?

Comment: The first procedure calculates $a^{2^n}$ while the second one calculates $a^n$. See for example [Fast exponentiation algorithm - How to arrive at it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898234/fast-exponentiation-algorithm-how-to-arrive-at-it/).

Comment: @dxiv. Thank you. The question is to devise algorithm based on the first algorithm to evaluate $a^n$. So you are saying the second algorithm does answer the question please?

Comment: I think that it is important to understand *descending recursive functions*.  For example, an algorithm to return $(n!) ~: n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ is : if $n=1$ then return $(1)$.  Else return $[n \times (n-1)!].$

Comment: @Avra No, not saying that. I suggest you read the linked question and answers.

Comment: @dxiv. This is very helpful. Thank you. I see this is known as exponentiaon by squaring.

Comment: This becomes crystal clear if you write the exponent in binary Horner form, e.g. see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/119375/242) in the dupe.

Comment: @Avra Or sometimes square-and-multiply. You can find several questions about this on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) as well.