# Efficient calculation of large exponents using the Pingala's algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, factoring

I was reading about how to efficiently calculate large exponents $\pmod m$ in the context of primality testing.
A way is binary expansion. So if we need to calculate if $a$ is a witness of the non-primality of $91$ we would have to compute: $a^{90}$ and an efficient way to do that would be to notice that the binary expansion of $90 = 64 + 16 + 8 + 2$ and hence we can just create a table and using the successive squaring method we could calculate $x^{90}$ with just $7$ multiplications since (e.g. for $x = 3$):

| $x^{2^e}$ | $\pmod {91}$ |
| --- | --- |
| $3^1$ | 1 |
| $3^2$ | $9$ |
| $3^4$ | $81$ |
| $3^8$ | $9$ |
| $3^{16}$ | $81$ |
| $3^{32}$ | $9$ |
| $3^{64}$ | $81$ |

So we have: $3^{90} = 3^{64}\cdot 3^{16}\cdot 3^{8}\cdot 3^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod {91}$

So far, it is clear but then I came about what seems to be a more generic (?) and efficient approach for calculating large exponent's which is the Pingala's algorithm.
From what I understand, the algorithm (working on the exponent) proceeds to halve it (same process as when we calculate the binary version of a decimal) but if in the process of halving the number if odd, it first subtracts $1$ and then halves.
Then it follows the reverse process (bottom up) for the multiplication of a number where if the number was halved, we square the current number, otherwise we square and then multiply by the number.
Here is an example for simplifying $3^{666} \pmod {667}$. The left column goes top-down where if a number is even is halved, if a number is odd, first we subtract by $1$ and then half.
The right column goes bottom up, if we have divided a number we square, if we also subtracted we multiply by $3$ after squaring

| Exponent $e$ | $3^e \pmod {667}$ |
| --- | --- |
| $666$ | $660$ |
| $333$ | $188$ |
| $332$ | $285$ |
| $166$ | $187$ |
| $83$ | $39$ |
| $82$ | $13$ |
| $41$ | $512$ |
| $40$ | $393$ |
| $20$ | $547$ |
| $10$ | $353$ |
| $5$ | $243$ |
| $4$ | $81$ |
| $2$ | $9$ |
| $1$ | $3$ |

Apparently this process simplifies $3^{666} \equiv 660 \pmod {667}$

But I am lost understanding what is the idea/intuition here. I thought it does binary expansion, but can't understand why $1$ is subtracted. Additionally following the idea bottom up I re-wrote as follows:

$$
(((((((((3^2)^2\cdot 3)^2)^2)^2\cdot 3)^2\cdot 3)^2)^2)\cdot 3)^2  
\Leftrightarrow  
(((3^{108}\cdot 3^{32} \cdot 3^{16} \cdot 3^2) \cdot 3)^4 \cdot 3)^2  
\Leftrightarrow    
3^{197} \cdot 3^{256} \cdot 3^{128} \cdot 3^{16} \cdot 3^{8} \cdot 3^2   
\Leftrightarrow   
3^{607}  
$$

So I don't really understand the process, and how come my calculations are different.

Could someone please help me with an explanation of the idea of the algorithm?

Comment: This *is* easiest to follow using the binary representation of the exponent, and it is known as binary exponentiation or square-and-multiply. See for example [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) and [Fast exponentiation algorithm - How to arrive at it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898234/fast-exponentiation-algorithm-how-to-arrive-at-it/).

Comment: @dxiv: Yes I did understand the binary representation as mentioned in the example with $90$ in my post. I don't understand the subtraction with $1$ and why that table bottom up gives $\equiv 660 \pmod 667$, why my following of the multiplications leds to $3^{607}$ and how do we know that $\equiv 660$ is the correct answer

Comment: @dxiv: did I misunderstood your comment? My question/confusion is about the pingala's algorithm and why we subtract $1$ and the final result.

Comment: Subtracting $1$ is part of the conversion to binary, think at how it works for $6=1010_2$ for example. As for the final result, I am not sure I follow your table. The algorithm is worked out step by step in the previous links, and $666=2^1 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^7 + 2^9=2+8+16+128+512$ so $3^{666}=3^2\cdot 3^8 \cdot 3^{16}\cdot 3^{128}\cdot 3^{512}\,$. Maybe you should choose a smaller exponent to check that you got the steps right.

Comment: @dxiv: that table is from a book, it is not mine (neither did I choose the exponent). You have broken down the binary representation but the example says that $\equiv 660 \pmod 667$. That part I can't verify with my calculations

Comment: @dxiv:Ok, after your comment I went and re-did the calculations a couple of more times, and I could get the same result as you specify. I made a mistake in my first attempt. What is not clear to me is that process from bottom up where we square/multiply by $3$ as we move up. The only part I am not clear is the square/multiply by $3$ as we move up. What's the intuition behind multiplying by $3$ when we have subtracted $1$?

Comment: @dxiv: Ok, I think I got it. Thank you for your help

Comment: Or just write it in an arbitrary base system. Power to the base, and multiply by the base you are exponentiating to that exponent raised to the digit ...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we need to compute $a^{22}$. We can do it by first computing $a^{11}$
and then squaring it to give $(a^{11})^2 = a^{22}$. We can compute $a^{11}$ similarly but since 11 is odd, we can express $a^{11} = a^{10}a$, and compute $a^{10}$ by first computing $a^5$ and squaring it. This recursive process can be repeated till the trivial subproblem of computing $a^1$. The subproblems created in this example have exponents as (in order of their creation): 11, 5, 2, 1.

Did you note how we handled the odd exponents $e$? By "subtracting 1" and halving the remaining even number $(e-1)$. And this action of subtracting is handled by the multiplication with $a$ after squaring.

The algorithm may be easy to understand and reason about if we consider the binary representation of $b$. It effectively processes the bits of $b$ from MSB to LSB: squaring for each bit, and additionally multiplying with $a$ for every 1 bit. For elaboration, you may refer to this [article](https://mathsanew.com/articles/algorithms_for_exponentiation.pdf) (written by me), section "Left-to-Right Binary Algorithm".