# Compute $2^{a}\pmod{p}$ in Minimum Number of Operations

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

In $\mathbb{Z_p}$,compute say $2^{41}\pmod{p}$ using at most group $8$ operations, $p$ is a prime.

I tried using Euler's Theorem and the fact 37 is prime using the gcd $1$ relation with $p-1,$ but how to narrow down to $8.$ or any other given number?

Comment: Try iterated squares.

Comment: [Iterated Squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is a standard computation tool.  It works particular well in modular arithmetic, as here.

Comment: Related: [Fast exponentiation algorithm - How to arrive at it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898234/fast-exponentiation-algorithm-how-to-arrive-at-it)

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/119374/11619). I don't know what is the best duplicate target, but this is sort of a FAQ.